# ProgressBar spamming Logcat

Tags: android, logcat, android-progressbar

In my application I use a progress bar with a custom drawable. Everything works perfectly fine except that my logcat get spammed with messages every time i call the `setProgress(int progress)` method of the progress bar.

The messages look like this:

> 12-09 17:11:54.250    5918-5918/com.mypackage D/ProgressBar﹕ setProgress =
> 33, fromUser = false 12-09 17:11:54.250    5918-5918/com.mypackage
> D/ProgressBar﹕ mProgress = 33mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax =
> 100

Those messages are definitely not coming from my code and I haven't found anything related using the search here.

Here's my progressbar in xml:

```
            <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_gpx_simulation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/myprogressbar"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
```

And this is how i am accessing it programmatically:

```
Progressbar progressBarGpxSimulation = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_gpx_simulation);
progressBarGpxSimulation.setProgress((int) progress);
```

Is there any way to turn these messages off? I am updating the progress quite often and can't read my other log messages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're working with Android Studio you can add some filters to your logcat output.

You can use this RegEx to exclude them from the log.

```
^(?!.*(ProgressBar)).*$
```

Comment: Not the answer i was hoping for but thanks for the regex. It works :)

Comment: Thanks it works ! :) 
I also added AbsSeekBar because it was spamming too :

^(?!.*(ProgressBar|AbsSeekBar)).*$

Answer (score 4):

I know it's unsightly and terribly long, but I, like you got annoyed with all of the extra logs when attempting to debug my apps. I build a list of all the problem ones and ignored them like so:

`tag:^(?!(MediaPlayer|dalvikvm|Activity|LocSvc|SignalStrength|Wifi|StateMachine|Parcel|CellInfo|qcom_|GpsLocationProvider|wpa_|AlarmManager|Telephony|LocationManager|StatusBar|Vold|PhoneInterface|PhoneGlobals|QCNEJ|SensorManager|NotificationService|SensorService|ThermalEngine|NotificationEventsAdapter|Weather_cast|Notification|NavigationBar|EDL|LGDMClient|NiLS|Tethering|Netd|Gcore|Util|AudioManager|BML))`

Add to, remove etc. BANG! And the nonsense is gone!

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you won'r be able to stop those. Those logs are coming from the device system itself and those might not come in some other devices. To see your other logs, its better if you use a different tag, so clearly see your important logs (here is the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) for more info).

```
Log.v(TAG, "Important Logs");
```

Here make your above `TAG` unique, and filter the same in the logcat.

Comment: Thanks for you input. I accepted the other answer because he had a solution for my case. Since I use a different TAG for every class, your solution wouldnt't have helped me.